# vuejs invoice transactions, input item push

Tags: vue.js, invoice

I am trying to make invoice transactions with vue js. my question is; The user may want to write a description for 1 product or may want to apply a discount. (BY REQUEST) I want the specified input to be shown whichever item he wants to add. (EVERY LINE CAN HAVE ONLY 1 EXPLANATION, DISCOUNT)

Therefore
on demand
When you press the "DESCRIPTION, DISCOUNT AND DISCOUNT RATE" buttons, the input of the relevant line will be pushed."

Thank you in advance for your help.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mesutuca/Ls4n1k2h/3/)

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        invoiceItems: [
            {
                name: "",
                quantity: 0,
                unit_price: 0,
                vat_rate: 18,
                net_total: 0,
                description: '',
                discount_value: 0,
                discount_rate:'usd'
            },
        ],
    },
    methods: {
        addInvoice() {
            this.invoiceItems.push({
                name: "",
                quantity: 0,
                unit_price: 0,
                vat_rate: 18,
                net_total: 0,
                description: '',
                discount_value: 0,
                discount_rate:'usd'
            });
        },
        removeIncoiceItem(index) {
            this.invoiceItems.splice(index, 1);
        },
    },
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <section class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th style="width:17%">Name</th>
            <th style="width:14%">Unit Price</th>
            <th style="width:15%">Vat Rate</th>
            <th style="width:20%">Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
      <div v-for="(item, index) in invoiceItems" :key="index" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="text" v-model="item.name">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="text" v-model="item.unit_price">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="text" v-model="item.net_total">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add Description</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Add Discount</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Add discount rate</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="removeIncoiceItem(index)">X</button>
          </div>
          <div  class="row" style="margin-top:20px;">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <input type="text" placeholder="description">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete Desc.</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" placeholder="discount_value">
                <select class="form-select-new">
                  <option value="dollar">USD</option>
                  <option value="percent">&</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete Disc.</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <input type="text" placeholder="discount rate">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete discount rate</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div style="margin-top:10px">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" @click="addInvoice()"> Add Item</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I wrote it in the question, but I'll say it again. I want the explanation input to be opened when the user clicks on the explanation button at any time. likewise discount and discount rate, and can delete it at any time.

Comment: invoice Items > add description.

Answer (score 0):

To show the input only when you press a button you should use `v-if` and check if the key exist on the item.
I will show you an example for `description` but you can apply it to all the inputs you want.

So when you add new item, add it without `description` like so:

```js
methods: {
        addInvoice() {
            this.invoiceItems.push({
                name: "",
                quantity: 0,
                unit_price: 0,
                vat_rate: 18,
                net_total: 0,
            });
        },
    },
```

And check if `item.description` exists on the `input` of `description`:

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="text" v-if="item.description !== undefined" v-model="item.description" placeholder="description"> </div>

...

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @click="addDesc(index)" >Add Description</button>

...

<div class="col-md-2">
   <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="deleteDesc(index)" >Delete Desc.</button>
</div>
```

The `addDesc` method will add the key to the item and set it as empty:

```js
addDesc(index){
   Vue.set(this.invoiceItems[index], "description", "");
}
```

The `deleteDesc` method will remove the key entirely from the item:

```js
deleteDesc(index){
   Vue.delete(this.invoiceItems[index], "description");
}
```

Now when you click on `add description` button - the `description` input will appear, and when you click `delete description` button - the `description` input will disappear.

Comment: I applied as you said, no shape reaction, it doesn't work.

Comment: and a situation like this, in the first place, I don't want the explanation to be obvious.
When the user clicks on "addDesc", I want to add a description to the form, and when he wants to delete it, when "deleteDesc" is clicked, I want it to be removed from the form.

Comment: I understand now what your question was. I updated the answer - you can try it now

Comment: your answer is not working for me right now. can you try jsfiddle yourself

Comment: I figured out the problem, it was my mistake. on the `v-if` you need the check if `item.description !== undefined` because when you check only `item.description` it will not pass if it is an empty string. I updated the answer as well.